# In-App purchases in Update

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0, ios4, in-app-purchase

I'm developing an update to an application. The application was originally free but I want to add in-app purchases.

Of course, I would like to test the application and make sure that the in-app purchase work well before submitting it to the AppStore.

I'm able to test the in-app purchases and they work well. However, I can only do that if I *remove* the previous version (which I install through the AppStore). If I don't remove the previous version, no purchasable objects are returned in:

```
- (void)productsRequest:(SKProductsRequest *)request didReceiveResponse:(SKProductsResponse  *)response
```

I would tend to think that it's ok but I want to make sure people will be able to see the in-app purchases in the new version.

Any suggestion?

Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

When you release update to your app having inApp functionality,once the user chooses to update your application through App Store,the new code having inApp functionality,New UI everything is updated.So don't worry the user will be able to view your inApp purchase module.

Thanks